# How do I show that $\gcd(a^2, b^2) = 1$ when $\gcd(a,b)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

How do I show that $\gcd(a^2, b^2) = 1$ when $\gcd(a,b)=1$?

I can show that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ implies $\gcd(a^2,b)=1$ and $\gcd(a,b^2)=1$.  But what do I do here?

Comment: $a^2$ and $b^2$ have the same prime factors as $a$ and $b$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint**: You've shown that $\gcd(y,b^2)=1$ when $\gcd(y,b)=1.$ What happens when $y=a^2$?

Answer (score 12):

The following proof is less informative than the posted proofs, but it is kinda cute. Recall the theorem of Bézout which says that $c$ and $d$ are relatively prime if and only if there exist integers $s$ and $t$ such that $cs+dt=1$.

Let $x$ and $y$ be integers such that $ax+by=1$. Now **cube** both sides. We get 
$$a^2(ax^3+3x^2by)+b^2(3axy^2+by^3)=1,$$
and therefore by the theorem of Bézout $a^2$ and $b^2$ are relatively prime.

Comment: That _is_ cute!  Very cool.  (We can't just square, of course, because the $abxy$ cross term has first powers of both $a$ and $b$ in it, but going to the cube ensures that every term has at least one of $a$ and $b$ raised to the second power.) This would generalize to all higher powers by just taking the right power of the equation $ax+by=1$ too...

Comment: Yes, there are whole slews of GCD theorems for which Bezout gives a quick proof without arguments about prime factorizations. You can square to prove that $(a,b)=1\implies (a,b^2)=1$. And then note the same proof shows taht $(b^2,a)=1\implies $(b^2,a^2)=1$.

Comment: Why is this less informative? It shows explicitly that appeals to prime factorization are unnecessary, and provides us with an algorithm to verify the result (by exhibiting witnesses $t,w$ such that $a^2t+b^2w=1$).

Comment: For a first number-theory course, the multiplicative structure of the natural numbers has a more concrete feel. Bezout's theorem may by contrast feel like magic, until one internalizes its algebraic content.

Answer (score 5):

gcd$(a,b)=1$ if and only if no prime divides a and b. A prime divides $a^2$ if and only if it divides a. Therefore a number divides $a^2$ and $b^2$ if and only if it divides $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, this means exactly that $a$ and $b$ do not have any prime factors in common. Any common factor would constitute a common divisor. If $a$ and $b$ have some prime factors in common, then the product of those common factors (including any repeated ones of higher multiplicity) is the greatest common divisor.

> For instance $24 = 2 \cdot 3\cdot 4$ and $60 = 3\cdot 4\cdot 5$. The common factors are $3$ and $4$ and so $\gcd(24, 60) = 3\cdot 4 = 12$.

If we take an integer $a$ and square it, the resulting integer $a^2$ does not have any new prime factors which are not already present in $a$. It simply has the same factors, with double the multiplicity.

> For instance $12 = 3\cdot 2\cdot 2$, and $144 = 12^2 = (3\cdot 2\cdot 2)(3\cdot 2 \cdot 2) = 3\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2$.

So if $a$ and $b$ have no prime factors in common, then $a^2$ and $b^2$ have no prime factors in common either, and so $\gcd(a^2, b^2) = 1$.